# How can I pass a variable from PHP to LESS?

Tags: css

I used LESS auto compiler in my theme (I followed [this tutorial](http://www.tailored4wp.com/how-to-use-less-auto-compiler-in-your-next-wordpress-project-quick-tip-361/)) to precompile my LESS files into CSS in my theme (yes, I wanted to avoid using external plugin like WP-Less because I wanted to have everything out-of-the-box in my theme without installing additional plugins).

Now I have few LESS files (variables.less, layout.less, structure.less, and so on...) and everything works perfectly. Now I've added few options to my [Theme Customizer](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API), some of them are related to colors. So now I have two questions:

1. How can I update specific variables in my LESS files using only functions.php or header.php - is there a way for that? (reason: let's say I've changed Background Color, which is one of my LESS variables, from Theme Customizer)
2. How can I add some LESS code "inline" (for example in header.php) so it could be precompiled as well?

Comment: Do you have an idea if this is possible in generic LESS context? Before WP is involved?

Comment: @Rarst not sure but my subconsciousness says 'yes'. there's something about: http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#setting_variables_from_php - but I'm not sure how to use it in my case..